# Issue to order products by price

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to order products by price with one link for low to high and the other high to low,
But after I click "low to high" or "high to low" the order is not changing, it stays on the same page but the url is changing.

this is the function in the controller:

```
public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC')
{
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);

    if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) {

        $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```

this is the route:

```
  Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort?}', 'ShopController@products');
```

those are the link from the view, the view is content.products

```html
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}" style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

the model:

```
class Product extends Model {


static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data){

    $data['products']=$data['category']=[];


    if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)->first()){

        $category= $category->toArray();
        $data['category']=$category;
        $data['title']=$data['title']. ' | ' . $category['title'];


        if ($products=Categorie::find( $category['id'])->products){

            $data['products']= $products->toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing parameter just like category_url without appending it to sorting- string

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, can u show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's problem in your condition, but for the problem the page is not change. I think you can make your return outside the `if` statement. So the code should be like this:

```php
public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC')
{
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);

    if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) {

        $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();
    }

    return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
}
```

It will give you little error, but I think your page will change :D

Comment: changed it to that. it still the same, the url is changing but the order of the products is the same

Comment: Is this the same page? but you want to make the order is changed?

Comment: ye it's the same page, I want to stay in the same page and only the order of the products will change according the url

Comment: when you refresh the page with the changed URL, the order still not working?

Comment: yes, the order still not working after refresh the page with the URL

Comment: can you edit your post with give more information, maybe add example data, show us the Model, the view, or something else. I will try it in my laptop

Comment: if you think that is troublesome, you can debug it by yourself. You can use `dd()` method before `return view()`. This `dd()` method is like `dump()` method, and I think we need to check the data before pass it to the view

Answer (score 0):

In View -

```
<a href="{{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting')}}?sort=ASC" style="color:black"> High to low</a>
```

In Route -

```
Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting', 'ShopController@products');
```

In Controller -

```
 public function products(Request $request, $category_url)
{
    $data = Input::all();

    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);

    if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) 
        {

            if( !isset($data['sort']) )
               $data['sort'] = 'ASC';

    $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $data['sort'])->get();

            return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
        }
}
```

Comment: im getting an error  ShopController.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

Comment: Add  - 
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input; 
at top of your controller

Comment: I added this, now it doesn't show the error but still the order doesn't change.

Comment: whats the datatype of the price column?

Comment: the data type is decimal(8,1)

Comment: it says Undefined variable: category1

Comment: you have to define $category1 before using it in the products query.

Comment: ok i defiend it:public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC')
{
    $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first(); 
 $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'));

if(!isset($data['sort']) || $data['sort'] == 'ASC')
{
 $products = $products->orderby('price','ASC');
}
else
{
 $products = $products->orderby('price','DESC');
}

$pr = $products->get();

return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
           
           
        
   
   }

Comment: now it says Undefined variable: category (View: in products.blade.view

Comment: I added this on the begging                                                                                        Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);                                                now it doesn't show the error but still doesn't change the order of the products

Comment: If you are still not getting the results than dd($data) and check what parameters are getting passed to the controller.

Comment: ok now it changed it to be automtically to be order low to high but if u click "high to low" it doesn't chnage

Comment: whats the result of dd when you click "high to low" ?

Comment: where should I add the dd?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vPiwWxGJ - If you get 1 then ASC code is getting executed else if you get 2 then DESC code

Comment: then please check the parameter being passed from the view. Your code is working correctly. The only issue is the parameter whick is being passed.

Comment: those are the links, like u wrote:                                                                                  <a href=" {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting')}}?sort=ASC" style="color:black">Low to high</a> |
  <a href=" {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting')}}?sort=DESC" style="color:black">High to Low</a>

Comment: this is the url  public/shop/vase/sorting?sort=DESC

Comment: it says     syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) on
                return view('content.products')->with('data'=>$data)->with('products',$pr);

Comment: change ->with('data'=>$data) to ->with('data',$data) and @RO.IT please don't act like a baby act like a developer these small things can be fixed by you

Comment: ok sorry,there is another problem it says Undefined index: category_url on    $category1 = Categorie::where('url','=', $data['category_url'])->first();

Comment: Please check the category_url paramter that is being sent use dd for this.

Comment: This error would have arrived only if it isn't able to find - $data['category_url']

Comment: sorry my bad now you cannot pass parameters to the function name. Now these will be accessed in the data parameter like $data['sort']

Comment: Do u know what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry, thats it i don't know what the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set products in data.

```
if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) {
    self::$data['products'] = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();
}
```